# Decomposition of interest rate risk

Tags: econometrics

Hi  I needed some clarification on something. I have three variables:

- $V_1$ which is an indicator of an interest rate risk premia
- $V_2$ which is an indicator of a credit risk premia
- $V_3$ which is an indicator of a liquidity risk premia.

While in theory the relationship of: 
$$V_1 = V_2 + V_3$$ should hold; I'm struggling to find a good modelling technique that can decompose $V_1$ into subcomponents that relate to $V_2$ and $V_3$. I am searching for something beyond a vector auto-regressive model.
My question is would State space modelling help me in this decomposition.